# MGF of a Multivariate Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

This question appeared on one of the challenge questions without solutions on my coursenotes. I couldn't wrap my head around multivariate vectors so any help would be much appreciated.

Let $Y=(Y_1,Y_2,Y_3)'$ be a $3\times 1$ vector of r.v. having a multivariate distribution ($Y\sim MVN(\mu,\sigma)$). Then the MGF of $Y$ is:

$$M(t)=\exp\left({\mu't + \frac{t'\sum t}{2}}\right)$$ for $t=\left(t_1,t_2,t_3 \right)'$

Now suppose

$$\mu=\begin{pmatrix} 5\\3\\6\end{pmatrix} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \sum=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1/2 & 1/2 \\ 1/2 & 1 & 1/2 \\ 1/2 & 1/2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Find MGF of $W=X_2-X_1$ and hence determine the distribution of $W$.
If $V=X_1+X_2$, find the joint MGF of $V$ and $W$ and hence their joint distribution.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You've used a lower-case $\sigma$ in the expression $MVN(\mu,\sigma)$ and a capitaal $\Sigma$ on the next line, even though they refer to the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't normally do this by using MGFs.  Here's how I'd do it.  (Later, I may figure out the most felicitous way to do it using MGFs directly; then I post that below this.)

$$X_1-X_2 = [1,-1,0]\begin{bmatrix} X_1 \\ X_2 \\ X_3 \end{bmatrix},$$
so
$$
\operatorname{var}(X_1-X_2) = [1,-1,0]\Sigma\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}\quad\text{(A $1\times 1$ matrix, thus a scalar.)}
$$
and
$$
\mathbb E(X_1-X_2) = [1,-1,0]\mu.
$$

Next, we have
$$
\begin{bmatrix} X_1-X_2 \\ X_1+X_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} X_1 \\ X_2 \\ X_3 \end{bmatrix}.
$$
So
$$
\operatorname{var} \begin{bmatrix} X_1-X_2 \\ X_1+X_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\Sigma\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\quad\text{A $2\times2$ matrix.}
$$
and
$$
\mathbb E\begin{bmatrix} X_1-X_2 \\ X_1+X_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \mu.
$$

Once you've found the expected value and the variance, you can plug them into the formula for the MGF.